# Locked SSH to a single IP and then lost that IP so I'm now locked out of the server

Tags: networking, server, ssh, iptables, rescue-mode

I thought locked SSH access to my IP would be a good thing but now I'm completely locked out and nothing I do in rescue mode seems to work.

I've tried changing/removing/uninstalling iptables but nothing I do in rescue mode seems to save and as soon as I boot the machine back up from the HDD all the settings have returned :/

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: It's currently running 18.04

Comment: I tried changing the SSH port but that doesn't save after reboot either

Comment: If you can't access your server via ssh or some web console, you have to ask your provider to fix that for you.

Comment: The issue is, I'm using OVH and they haven't been answering anyone's tickets for weeks

Answer (score 0):

Many VPS hosting companies provide "console" access to fix problems like this. In a comment you mentioned you are using OVH. Here is their help page explaining how to use their implementation of console access: https://docs.ovh.com/us/en/public-cloud/access_console_horizon/

Answer (score 0):

Tom Brossman was correct there is a console but it's in a slightly different place for dedicated servers.

I feel a bit dumb so I'm going to leave this here for any other dumbasses like me :P

https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/dedicated/use-ipmi-dedicated-servers/